# Meteor React Form won't change value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor

A bit confused on why exactly my inputs won't update. Essentially, I want to have a profile page. The page is just a form with the fields you can edit. If you already have values for some things (name, etc), I want those to automatically be filled in as the user types with the new values. I imagine it has something to do with trying to overwrite the value with is a "prop" so then I should put the props into "state" for the items. However, if I try to set the state the props, they don't pick up the subscription values.

So again, the goal would just be to have the page load, existing values in the person's user document slide into the appropriate fields, edit the fields and submit the changes. Just the input won't change the value after I try setting it to the props.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Thanks

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { createContainer } from 'meteor/react-meteor-data';
import { getPath } from 'underscore-contrib/underscore.object.selectors';

export default class Profile extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({value: e.target.value});
  }

  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(e);
    console.log(this.refs)

    // verify the fields
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="profile">
        <h1 className="ui header blue">Profile</h1>

        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)} className="profile-form ui form">


          <div className="three fields">
            <div className="field">
              <label>First name</label>
              <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" ref="name.firstName" value={this.props.firstName} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
            </div>
            <div className="field">
              <label>Last name</label>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" ref="name.lastName" value={this.props.lastName} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
            </div>
            <div className="field">
              <label>Nickname</label>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Nickname" ref="name.nickName" value={this.props.nickName} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div className="two fields">
            <div className="field">
              <label>Phone</label>
              <input type="text" placeholder="xxx.xxx.xxxx" ref="phoneNumber" value={this.props.phone} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
            </div>
            <div className="field">
              <label>Email</label>
              <input type="email" placeholder="you@email.com" ref="email" value={this.props.email} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div className="four fields">
            <div className="field">
              <label>DOB</label>
              <input type="text" placeholder="YYYY/DD/MM" ref="body.dob" value={this.props.dob} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
            </div>
            <div className="field">
              <label>City</label>
              <input type="text" placeholder="City" ref="address.city" value={this.props.city} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
            </div>
            <div className="field">
              <label>State</label>
              <input type="text" placeholder="State" ref="address.state" value={this.props.state} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
            </div>

          </div>

          <div className="three fields">
            <div className="field">
              <label>Height</label>
              <div className="ui right labeled input">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Enter height" ref="body.height" value={this.props.height} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                <div className="ui label">in</div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="field">
              <label>Weight</label>
              <div className="ui right labeled input">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Enter weight" ref="body.weight" value={this.props.weight} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                <div className="ui label">lbs</div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="field">
              <label>Gender</label>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Male..." ref="body.gender" value={this.props.gender} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
            </div>
          </div>

          <button className="ui button" type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>

      </div>
    )
  }
}

Profile.propTypes = {
  "firstName": PropTypes.string,
  "lastName" : PropTypes.string,
  "nickName" : PropTypes.string,
  "phone"    : PropTypes.string,
  "email"    : PropTypes.string,
  "dob"      : PropTypes.string,
  "city"     : PropTypes.string,
  "state"    : PropTypes.string,
  "height"   : PropTypes.string,
  "weight"   : PropTypes.string,
  "gender"   : PropTypes.string
}

export default ProfileContainer = createContainer(() => {
  Meteor.subscribe("Meteor.users.publish.name");
  Meteor.subscribe("Meteor.users.publish.phone");
  Meteor.subscribe("Meteor.users.publish.body");
  Meteor.subscribe("Meteor.users.publish.address");

  // build out fields I want in a safe way
  let dict = {
    "firstName": _.getPath(Meteor.user(), 'name.firstName'),
    "lastName" : _.getPath(Meteor.user(), 'name.lastName'),
    "nickName" : _.getPath(Meteor.user(), 'name.nickName'),
    "phone"    : _.getPath(Meteor.user(), 'phone'),
    "email"    : _.getPath(Meteor.user(), 'emails.0.address'),
    "dob"      : _.getPath(Meteor.user(), 'body.dob'),
    "city"     : _.getPath(Meteor.user(), 'address.city'),
    "state"    : _.getPath(Meteor.user(), 'address.state'),
    "height"   : _.getPath(Meteor.user(), 'address.height'),
    "weight"   : _.getPath(Meteor.user(), 'body.weight'),
    "gender"   : _.getPath(Meteor.user(), 'body.gender')
  }

  // create a object to only review the profile items that you want to actually look at
  return {
    "firstName": _.isString(dict.firstName) ? dict.firstName : "",
    "lastName" : _.isString(dict.lastName)  ? dict.lastName  : "",
    "nickName" : _.isString(dict.nickName)  ? dict.nickName  : "",
    "phone"    : _.isString(dict.phone)     ? dict.phone     : "",
    "email"    : _.isString(dict.email)     ? dict.email     : "",
    "dob"      : _.isString(dict.dob)       ? dict.dob       : "",
    "city"     : _.isString(dict.city)      ? dict.city      : "",
    "state"    : _.isString(dict.state)     ? dict.state     : "",
    "height"   : _.isString(dict.height)    ? dict.height    : "",
    "weight"   : _.isString(dict.weight)    ? dict.weight    : "",
    "gender"   : _.isString(dict.gender)    ? dict.gender    : ""
  };
}, Profile);
```

Answer (score 0):

To be able to update your field value, they must be recorded as a state. Let's take an example:

```
<div className="field">
  <label>First name</label>
  <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" ref="name.firstName" value={this.props.firstName} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
</div>
```

Here, you set your value to `this.props.firstName` which won't change onChange. To have it default to the prop value but be able to update it, pass it as a state.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    firstName: props.firstName,
  };
}
```

Then pass the state in your input field. Also, the `handleChange` function is always updating the same state `value`. You need to tell your function which state to update. You can remove your bind from the constructor and us it as follow:

```
handleChange(key, e) {
  this.setState({ [key]: e.target.value })
}
```

and in the render

```
<input type="text" placeholder="First Name" ref="name.firstName" value={this.state.firstName} onChange={ () => this.handleChange('firstName'); }/>
```

Comment: Hmm, main issue that still happens though, is that the state is initially still empty. So the value when the page loads is still "". Once the subscription is ready, state won't be updated since the constructor only runs the one time.

Comment: I should add, I've seen other solutions that essentially update the value in the DB as you type, but this seems like a network chatter just to accomplish updating a input. Plus this kind of defeats the purpose of a "submit" button, which I could remove, but it would still be good to get this solution right as well.

Comment: I had to update the state reactively. So kept your usage of state, but added, ```componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.setState(nextProps);
  }```

Comment: OK, I see. Just for curiosity, did you try using a `defaultValue`? Combined with the `onChange` that could allow you to update the value (and the state) when the props rerender, without having to call `componentWillReceiveProps`. i.e. something like:
`<input type="text" value={this.state.name} defaultValue={this.props.name} />`

Again, not sure this would work, just a suggestion.
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#default-value